# Change speed of vibrator with AudioToolbox

Tags: objective-c, ios, vibration

Im trying to find out how to change the speed of the vibrator so it can go faster or slower.

```
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Im using AudioToolbox framwork

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this.

Comment: This caught my attention, really. :D

Comment: i see all these vibrator apps that are able to. hmm

Comment: no I don't think you can change it without using private APIs. However you can change the length of the vibration by using another framework... can't remember which though